# Too many Ifs to check variable really contains a valid, 4 digit year

Tags: php, regex

The following if statement works but it's ugly and I have a feeling the same **could be achieved with a preg_match REGEX**. How?

Basically I don't know how to limit the amount of digits to 4 in regex yet. And once the 4 numerical digit criteria is met, I would like to limit the return of true to between 2019 and 2025.

Sample regex:

```
/* digits only, no dots */
function is_digits($element) {
    return !preg_match ("/[^0-9]/", $element);
}
```

Sample PHP

```
// SET $TARGET_YEAR TO current year in [yyyy] format.
// Is set, Is not empty, Is numeric, Is 4 digits long?
if(isset($_GET["year"]) && !empty($_GET["year"]) && is_numeric($_GET["year"]) && strlen($_GET["year"]) == 4) {
  // WE HAVE A REAL YEAR.
  // SET $TARGET_YEAR TO target year in [yyyy] format.
  self::$TARGET_YEAR = $_GET["year"];
} else {
  // WE DON'T HAVE A REAL YEAR.
  // SET $TARGET_YEAR TO current year in [yyyy] format.
  self::$TARGET_YEAR = date('Y');
}
```

Comment: `return preg_match ("/^[0-9]{4}$/", $element);`. If there can be 1 to 4 digits, use `{1,4}` instead of `{4}`.

Comment: `^\d{4}$` for four digits, `^\d{0,4}$` for 0 to 4 digits

Comment: And once the 4 numerical digit criteria is met, I would like to limit the return of true to between 2019 and 2025. Is this also possible in the same regex?

Comment: these should be answers

Comment: Or for constraining to realistic dates: `/^(19|20|21)\d\d$/`

Comment: just do: `return  $element > 2019 && $element < 2025`. If you know the range why bother to validate with regex ?

Comment: Yep, that's the beauty of PHP, you can work treat the same variable as a string (doing regex) and as a number (doing < and >).

Comment: I was just going to bring that up... niiiice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions are unnecessary for such a simple check. Your existing code could be reduced to this:

```
$year = (int)$_GET["year"] ?? 0;
if ($year >= 2019 && $year <= 2025) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Just [cast the string as an integer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) and then check the range. If the string is not a valid number the cast will turn it to 0. If the value isn't set, the [null coalesce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) will also turn it to zero.

Comment: The `??` is available as of PHP 7.0.

Comment: PHP 7.0 is end of life, you should be on version 7.1 minimum.

Comment: The answer you accepted a) doesn't work, and b) would be a waste of resources even if it did work; regex parsing is heavy. Your original idea was the wrong way to do this, accepting an asnwer "because it more closely matches the original" question is not how this is supposed to work. Especially if you aren't going to use the accepted answer.

Comment: @ASPiRE I agree with miken. Regex is for pattern matching and not for range checking. Your `And once the 4 numerical digit criteria is met` anyway satisfies in the condition check.

Comment: Sorry fellas, I had to go to work a few minutes after I posted this. I have accepted this answer after all. @miken32 I could swear I have been punished on here for offering a solution that was more efficient but not what the OP requested. It's good to read someone with your rep writing otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. When you put in curly braces number 4 it will allow only 4 numbers if you use 0,4 it will allow 0 to 4 digits.

```
/* digits only, no dots */
function is_digits($element) {
    $element = preg_match ("/^[0-9]{4}$/", $element);

    if($element > 2019 && $element < 2025) {
       return true; //Or $element
    } else {
       return false; //Or something else you want
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you kindly incorporate `return $element > 2019 && $element < 2025` in this validation just for thoroughness regarding previous comments?

Comment: Something like that?

Comment: Accepted this answer because it more closely matches the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a built-in validate filter:

```
$opts = ['options' => ['min_range' => 2019, 'max_range' => 2025]];

if($date = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'year', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $opts)) {
    //yes
}
```

Comment: Ok. It seems that the if statement is returning an array instead of a boolean. This is what var_dump shows whether the year is in range or not; `array(1) { ["date"]=> bool(false) }` or `array(1) { ["date"]=> bool(true) }`. As you can see, because it is the value of the key value pair that is set to boolean, checking the array never returns anything that can be checked b this if statement.

Comment: After a little more research I have found that `filter_input_array` wont return false if any filter fails. Rather it will *return an array* with the appropriate *items set to false* if they failed the filter or null if they weren't set. Could you kindly update your answer to reflect this check?